# Count how many elements are in an array created by make_set in kusto language

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

How to count the elements in an array created by make_set in KQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `array_length()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arraylengthfunction